# FIO benchmark replay fails in case of size 0

Tags: benchmark

Abhishek Srivastava
Member
 0
1 post
Report post 
Posted yesterday at 01:46 PM
I have downloaded Financial application traces  in standard *.spc format and then converted it into fio format. Now when I use those traces to replay it through FIO, it fails at places,  where trace has read operation with size 0 (as part of those standard traces) and gives following error:

io       3229  get_io_u: zero buflen on 0x55e45819f580
io       3229  get_io_u failed
fio: filesetup.c:1670: get_file: Assertion `fio_file_open(f)' failed.
fio: pid=3229, got signal=6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your traces are referring to files/disks that don't exist on your system. If all the I/O only needs to go to one file/device you could look into using [`replay_redirect`](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-replay-redirect) ...

Comment: Thanks, actually I was getting this problem in cases where zero size reads were present in traces.